# Financial Force

Tags: financialforce

I keep getting this error everytime i try to make something visable in Financial Force.

Why do I have this problem? How can I fix it?

```
Permission Create zDeprecated:Forecast Calculation Logs depends on permission(s): Read zDeprecated:Forecast Calculations
Permission Delete zDeprecated:Forecast Calculation Logs depends on permission(s): Read zDeprecated:Forecast Calculations
Permission Edit zDeprecated:Forecast Calculation Logs depends on permission(s): Read zDeprecated:Forecast Calculations
Permission Read zDeprecated:Forecast Calculation Logs depends on permission(s): Read zDeprecated:Forecast Calculations
Permission Create Skill Set Skills depends on permission(s): Read Skills and Certifications
Permission Delete Skill Set Skills depends on permission(s): Read Skills and Certifications
Permission Edit Skill Set Skills depends on permission(s): Read Skills and Certifications
Permission Read Skill Set Skills depends on permission(s): Read Skills and Certifications
Permission Create Version Item Issues depends on permission(s): Read Versions
Permission Create Version Item Risks depends on permission(s): Read Versions
Permission Delete Version Item Issues depends on permission(s): Read Versions
Permission Delete Version Item Risks depends on permission(s): Read Versions
Permission Edit Version Item Issues depends on permission(s): Read Versions
Permission Edit Version Item Risks depends on permission(s): Read Versions
Permission Read Version Item Issues depends on permission(s): Read Versions
Permission Read Version Item Risks depends on permission(s): Read Versions
```

Comment: What is the "something" you're trying to make visible? What FinancialForce product are you using? Have you contacted Financial Force support?

Comment: I'm trying to add the "Action Views" to the tab menu for X-Profiles. Currently the tab settings says "Tab Hidden". When I try to change that to "Default On" I get those errors. Oddly enough, I in D4-Sandbox, I've got it to work but i can't get it to work in QA. However, & even more strange, if I try to move it back to "Tab Hidden" in D4 it bugs up again and gives me those errors. So I'm totally lost on how I'm supposed to make that go from "Tab Hidden" to "Default On" without getting those errors like a brick wall.

Comment: updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the "depends on permission(s)" error means that you are attempting to give access to an object that is on the child side of a master-detail relationship.

For example, we have FFPSA installed which has the "skill set skills" object. This object is a junction object between "skill set" and "skill/certification". If you attempt to give permission to skill set it makes perfect sense for you to see that error. Instead, you should be giving them permission to the parent objects.

### Update Based on Comments

That sounds like the profiles were set up, and then the application changed (possibly an upgrade) that modified the objects and settings essentially invalidating the permissions. When you go back to the profile to try to update it with something simple, you find out that all those permissions are no longer valid. I don't think that really changes the answer though. If you go back in and re-configure the perms for the profiles, you should be able to make the change you want to make.